# Spring Contract-First Web Services - Must Request and Response objects have similar names?

Tags: java, spring, web-services

When writing a contract-first web service with Spring Webservices, must the request and response objects share a name for in-out services?  That is, must service Foo have a FooRequest as an input and a FooResponse as an output?

All of the tutorials I've been finding have that naming convention, but I'd like to have, for example, a GetFoosByCriteria1Request, GetFoosByCriteria2Request and GetFoosByCriteria3Request all return a GetFoosResponse object.  Throwing a schema with all of those in it ends up producing a WSDL like:

```
<wsdl:binding name="FoosPortSoap11" type="tns:FoosPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetFoosByCriteria1">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="GetFoosByCriteria1Request">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetFoosByCriteria2">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="GetFoosByCriteria2Request">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetFoosByCriteria3">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="GetFoosByCriteria3Request">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetFoos">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:output name="GetFoosResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

Which is just no good.

I'm guessing it would be possible; we use WebServiceTemplate and DefaultWsdl11Definition beans and Camel routes to build/expose our web services, and I think the parts that try to pick out request/response objects is in DefaultWsdl11Definition... but not using DefaultWsdl11Definition is going to be a huge mess of configuration(that's why it's such a convenient 'default') .  Which might not be worth it anyway.

Comment: have you tried to let spring do the wsdl creation and see what the output is? "Spring-WS can create the WSDL for you, as explained in the section entitled...."

Comment: We're making the schema and letting Spring do that; the WSDL above is representative of what Spring publishes for us.

Comment: So have you tried to experiment with it to fit your needs?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know where to begin or if it'd even be worth it.  I think we have to get away from using DefaultWsdl11Definition, but the minute you do that it gets... messy at best.  That thing does a lot.  But no amount of tinkering with the schema itself is going to do the trick that I've found.

Comment: I wouldn't mess with this